# Windows Search - Is there a better way?

Tags: c#, windows-search

I have a requirement to search file in a given location for specified content. These files will be searched via a web-application (which may not necessarily be on the same server), and should update in near realtime.

After looking around for Scanning tools/code, I hit upon [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17507840/2505574) answer that indicated that you can programmatically hook into the built in Windows Search feature of windows.

Using the code below (more or less the answers code with a few minor tweaks), I have been able to successfully make this work on my machine:

```
public class WindowsSearchScanner
{
    private const string Query = @"SELECT System.ItemName FROM SystemIndex WHERE scope ='file:{0}' and FREETEXT('{1}')";

    public void DoSearch(string criteria, string path)
    {
        string connectionString = "Provider=Search.CollatorDSO;Extended Properties=\"Application=Windows\"";
        using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
        {
            string query = string.Format(Query, path, criteria);
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query, connection);
            connection.Open();

            List<string> result = new List<string>();

            OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            int count = 0;
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                result.Add(reader.GetString(0));
                Console.WriteLine(reader.GetString(0));

                count++;
            }
            Console.WriteLine(count + " Records Found");

            connection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

I have several queries regarding this:

1. Is there a *better* (i.e. more .Net) way of accessing the Windows Search, beyond using string queries?
2. Is there a way to parameterise the text? I tried straight up adding `OleDbParameters` to the command, but apparently the CollatorDSO doesn't support it. Obviously, I'd prefer not to have to sanitise the data beforehand - like SQL injection, it's likely I'll miss some potential avenue that will cause problems

   ```
   string query = @"SELECT System.ItemName FROM SystemIndex WHERE scope ='file:' + @path and FREETEXT(@text)";
   OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query, connection);

   command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("path", path));
   command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("text", criteria));

   connection.Open();
   ```
3. Can this be accessed from a remote machine?
4. Will this work even if the server does not have the relevant software installed - i.e. if the directory contains an excel file, will it index even if the server does not have office installed?

Comment: have you google? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff684395(v=vs.85).asp 3) ,4).
1) you can add windows function via import unsafe. 2) looks wierd old fashioned but i suppose there is no pther option for this approach

Comment: ssory http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff684395(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks @VladimirShmidt - that certainly helps. Although unfortunately it looks like it is still stuck in the 90s. I'll probably create a wrapper service to obfuscate the clunkiness out of my main code. If you want to write that up as an answer, I can mark it as the answer.

Comment: did you tried using ***wrapper service*** ? any sample about it ? You use _scope file_, not **folder** ? (`for search in many documents doc, tx, PDF, ...`

Comment: Is it possible to create your own OLE DB provider to create your own search service? The built in one is atrocious in certain situations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for 3) ,4) [msdn Using SQL and AQS Approaches to Query the Index](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff684395(v=vs.85).aspx)
for 1) you can try add windows function via import unsafe. 
for 2) looks wierd old fashioned but i suppose there is no other option for this approach

Answer (score 0):

You can go old-school and use FindStr in a Process/ProcessStartInfo.

Findstr (a command-line tool) is built in to your server and is able to access any location to which the user you are impersonating has access.

I tried this out in a small single-page implementation and i was able to read/ scan files on my local drive as well as UNC paths.

This could be an option for you. The output is text.