# Querying Windows Search Service via .NET: Permissions Issue?

Tags: .net, windows

I am attempting to search files on a website using the [Windows Search API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb231256%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), eactly as the accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17389403). Briefly:

```
var con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Search.CollatorDSO;EXTENDED PROPERTIES='Application=Windows'");
...
"SELECT System.ItemName FROM SystemIndex WHERE SCOPE='file:C:\inetpub\wwwroot\[MySite]' ";
```

However, it never returns any items.

I discovered that a wide-open query (no scope) only returns files within `C:\Users\[me]`

For instance, it finds files on my desktop, but not in C:\Windows. I am a local admin, and can find no mention of permission restrictions.

I've tried it in webforms and winforms both locally and deployed remotely. Same behavior.

Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering my own question.

My "problem" had nothing to do with permissions; it was caused by ignorance of how Windows Search works.

I stumbled upon an [Advanced Indexing Options](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/change-advanced-indexing-options) article from MSFT and realized that it was only indexing files in my user profile, start menu, and IE history. I manually added my website folder to the index and everything started working as if by magic.