# How to use Windows Search Service in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, search, filesystems, windows-search

I'm working on an application, an user can search for files or folders either on the local computer or on the network. I am using `DirectoryInfo.GetDirecotories()`.

1. But I also want to add the functionality that windows 7 uses for searching, I believe that uses indexing. I also saw **Windows Searching Service** on msdn, but I'm not sure which way is best: querying the indexed catalog or using the search service. Any suggestions?

Provide a small example in C# that searches the indexed catalog?

Comment: You mean something like this: [full text search in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17389403/windows-search-full-text-search-in-c-sharp)?

Comment: @bokibeg do you mean searching a "text file", if yes, then no I'm not looking for searching text in a document.

Comment: @bokibeg I am checking the link on your reply, yes thats what I am looking for, it is searching for files only, is it possible to leverage the scope to search for folders? and also is it possible to search the network drives?

Comment: I will come up with an example in few minutes.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

See the below example:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var connection = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Search.CollatorDSO;Extended Properties=""Application=Windows""");

    // File name search (case insensitive), also searches sub directories
    var query1 = @"SELECT System.ItemName FROM SystemIndex " +
                @"WHERE scope ='file:C:/' AND System.ItemName LIKE '%Test%'";

    // File name search (case insensitive), does not search sub directories
    var query2 = @"SELECT System.ItemName FROM SystemIndex " +
                @"WHERE directory = 'file:C:/' AND System.ItemName LIKE '%Test%' ";

    // Folder name search (case insensitive)
    var query3 = @"SELECT System.ItemName FROM SystemIndex " +
                @"WHERE scope = 'file:C:/' AND System.ItemType = 'Directory' AND System.Itemname LIKE '%Test%' ";

    // Folder name search (case insensitive), does not search sub directories
    var query4 = @"SELECT System.ItemName FROM SystemIndex " +
                @"WHERE directory = 'file:C:/' AND System.ItemType = 'Directory' AND System.Itemname LIKE '%Test%' ";           

    connection.Open();

    var command = new OleDbCommand(query4, connection);

    using (var r = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (r.Read())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(r[0]);
        }
    }

    connection.Close();

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

It's using OLE DB api to connect to the indexer service and use a SQL-like syntax to search `System` objects in its `SystemIndex` table. You have 4 example queries which do different things. All example queries will search in the `c:\` folder for items that contain `Test` in their names.

You can search for files, folders mails and possibly other media (depending on OS) on local or other machines. From what I have researched network drives are not supported since they can't be indexed but you can connect to other machines for which I assume RPC is used in the background which means you have to supply network credentials using a different api (e.g. System.Net).

Note that for any of this to work your indexing must be fully operational on the target machine (which it is *by default*). The api is corresponding to whatever you specify in your Indexing Options. This is the screen in question:

[image: indexing options]

The full list of properties for the `System` object can be found here:
[Property System Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff521735(v=vs.85).aspx). This object contains things such as URL, Path, Name, Date etc.

More interesting examples using different predicates (e.g. `scope` and `directory`) can be found here: [Windows Vista Search Syntax](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cheller/archive/2006/06/27/windows-vista-search-syntax-where-are-my-predicates.aspx). There is also a crude MSDN documentation: [SCOPE and DIRECTORY Predicates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb231257%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

I recommend you check out the documentation because you can do *a lot* of stuff with this api.

Comment: i know its been a while, but I'm reaching out to you again. You have already mentioned about searching network machine, but I was looking at [windows dev network](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb231257%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), _To query the local catalog of a remote computer, include the computer name before the catalog and a Universal Naming Convention (UNC) path on the remote computer in the SCOPE or DIRECTORY clause._

Comment: and found this example     ` SELECT System.ItemName FROM zarasmachine.SystemIndex WHERE SCOPE='file://zarasmachine/C:/Files/Reports' `, my question is, if i have access to the remote machine, this query won't work ?

Comment: A little late to the party here, but one interesting about using this API is that I haven't found a way to have it return results with partial numbers in it. For example, if I have a file named "abc12345.txt", and I use the search clause "WHERE System.FileName LIKE '%123%'", the file won't be returned. However LIKE '%12345%' would.

Comment: Theoretically.. Could someone write their own indexing service to replace Microsofts? Since Microsoft do not support Windows Search on Server 2012 / Server 2016 - and it's absolutely crap?

Comment: They do support windows search, not indexing services which was deprecated as of windows 2008. Windows Search is the replacer.