# C# Windows Search Service Unspecified Error: -2147219688(0x80040718)

Tags: c#, windows, windows-services, search-engine, oledbconnection

I'm writing a custom file-browser in WPF that used [Windows Search Service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb231257%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to search files from the system. I followed the syntax for file search that is written [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34340288/2600860) and [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cheller/2006/06/21/searching-for-windows-vista-search/). But when I run the program an exception is raised with the following message:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException'
>   occurred in System.Data.dll Additional information: Unspecified error:
>   -2147219688(0x80040718)

Here's the code that I'm using for file search:

```
List<string> result = new List<string>();
string connectionString = "Provider=Search.CollatorDSO;Extended Properties=\"Application=Windows\"";
OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);

string query = @"SELECT System.ItemName FROM SystemIndex " +
    @"WHERE SCOPE = 'file:O:/Design/_Revit Standards/Latest/Revit 2017 - Families' AND System.ItemName LIKE 'a%'";

OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query, connection);
connection.Open();


OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
{
    result.Add(reader.GetString(0));

}
connection.Close();
```

Would really appreciate if someone helps me with this error.

Comment: Is that O: drive mapped to a server? Can you try with a local folder like C:/Users or so to see if the code works in that case. Then you know if the scope is causing the problem.

Comment: Yes, 'O' is a network drive that I'm accessing. However I also have local 'E' drive which raises the same exception.. Am I missing something @rene ?

Comment: Hmm, okay. The scope was something that jumped at me so that is why i asked. I don't know what is wrong then.

Comment: @rene code is working fine with the 'C' drive path. Is there any syntax to perform the search on a network drive?

Comment: I  never tried but with the right permissions and if the  server is running search as well you might try `file://servername/C:/path/on/server`