# Doc and docx filetypes returns the same file

Tags: c#

I am trying to get the document files in the below mentioned path. so i set the file types as doc and docx.

In the documents folder, i have the file "issues.docx"

```
 string path1 = "C:\\Documents\\";
 var dir =  new DirectoryInfo(path1);
 string[] fileTypes = { "doc", "docx" };       
 var myFiles = fileTypes.SelectMany(dir.GetFiles);
```

This is the code i have used in my application. here it returns the issues.docx file two times. But it should return the files one time only.How can i achieve it without any change in `fileTypes`?

Comment: `*.doc` will also match `*.docx` (for legacy 8.3 naming support).  [Better to use `EnumerateFiles()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163162/can-you-call-directory-getfiles-with-multiple-filters)

Comment: EnumerateFiles() also return the same result

Comment: @Joy NTFS isn't a search engine. Performing two separate searches will result in two scans of all the files, resulting in double the time. It would be faster if you used `EnumerateFiles` to search for `*.doc*` files and split them by extension afterwards, eg with `ToDictionary`

Comment: I made `A.DOC` & `A.DOCX` in a directory, your code duplicates because it traverses *twice* and the  wildcards clash, `Directory.EnumerateFiles("c:\\null\\temp", "*.*").Where(s => s.EndsWith(".doc") || s.EndsWith(".docx"));` only returns each file once.

Comment: @Joy did you do what the linked answer shows or did you use the same faulty code with `EnumerateFiles` ? The linked question reads the matching files *once* then filters them

Comment: @panagiotis I have tried with the already posted code only.How do i proceed with your logic

Answer (score 2):

NTFS isn't a search engine. Performing two separate searches will result in two scans of all the files, taking double the time.

It would be faster if you used EnumerateFiles to search for *.doc* files and split them by extension afterwards, eg with ToDictionary.

```
var filesByExtension=dir.EnumerateFiles("*.doc?")
                        .ToDictionary(fi=>fi.Extension,fi=>fi);
```

You can also group the results, if you want, eg to calculate statistics:

```
dir.EnumerateFiles("*.doc?")
   .GroupBy(fi=>fi.Extension)
   .Select(g=>new {
                      Extension=g.Key,
                      TotalSize=g.Sum(f=>f.Length), 
                      Files=g.ToArray()
           });
```

If you want accelerated searching, you can use the Windows Search service. Calling it isn't straightforward though, you have to call it as if it were an [OLEDB database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17389403/windows-search-full-text-search-in-c-sharp). The results may *not* be accurate either, if the indexer is still scanning the files

**UPDATE**

If there is nothing common in the file types to search, filtering can be performed in a `Where` expression:

```
var extensions=new[]{".doc",".docx",".png",".jpg"};
dir.EnumerateFiles()
   .Where(fi=>extensions.Contains(fi.Extension))
   .GroupBy(fi=>fi.Extension)
   .Select(g=>new {
                      Extension=g.Key,
                      TotalSize=g.Sum(f=>f.Length), 
                      Files=g.ToArray()
           });
```

`Where` can be used to filter out small or large files, eg:

```
var extensions=new[]{".doc",".docx",".png",".jpg"};
dir.EnumerateFiles()
   .Where(fi=>extensions.Contains(fi.Extension) && fi.Length>1024)
   .GroupBy(fi=>fi.Extension)
   .Select(g=>new {
                      Extension=g.Key,
                      TotalSize=g.Sum(f=>f.Length), 
                      Files=g.ToArray()
           });
```

Comment: In my filetypes  i will get any file types like png, jpg, pdf etc. So How do i change this as generic solution ?

Comment: If you don't want to filter by a specific type, just don't use a pattern. You asked about `doc` and `docx` files though - your code made two separate calls for `doc` and `docx`. In any case, it's still a full scan. If you want to further filter the results, add a `Where` clause

Comment: This solution also returns the file two times. .

Comment: @Joy no it doesn't. `EnumerateFiles` runs only *once*. Unless you *do* have two files with the same name, eg in separate directories. Or you have one `.doc` and one `.docx` file

Comment: @Joy this is such a fundamental concept that you'll have to post a fully reproducible example. Trying to read files that only differ by the extension does *not* result in duplicates. `File1.doc` is a different file from `File1.docx`. If you ask for both extensions, both will appear in the results.

Comment: I return the results empty "enumeration yielded no results"

Comment: @Joy what code? What directory? What results? Duplicates or no result?
 Nobody can *guess* what you tried.